# How to change the content of a div dynamically when the input changes?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="text" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty" />
<div id="qtyvalue"><div>
```

There is an input text box on the page. I'm using Javascript to output the qtyvalue to the following div.

```
var qty =document.getElementById('qty').value;
document.getElementById('qtyvalue').innerHTML = qty;
```

Now, if the user enters a number in the text box, the value of qtyvalue will be changed accordingly, and I don't need to refresh the page. How should I change the code?

Comment: Place that code in an event handler assigned to the `.onchange` property of the input field?

Comment: Or on the `keyup` event to have it react directly while typing. (Like the counter below the comment-box here on stackoverflow.)

Comment: I edited the title so it is a bit clearer what's being asked.

Comment: Dan D,if using onchange,how to change the code. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it inside `keyup` event:

```
var input = document.getElementById('qty'); 
input.onkeyup = function() {
    document.getElementById('qtyvalue').innerHTML = input.value;    
}
```

But you should consider adding the same action on other events also: `change`, `paste`, `input`.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9cyXq/)

Comment: Added an answer for those who don't familiar with basic event handling.

Comment: Inferpse,if i want to use change, how to change the code,thank you

Comment: the same way you using `keyup` event - `input.onchange = function() {...`

Comment: Inferpse,if there are two input text or more, could i use onkeyup event?

Comment: Yes. Loop through them and set `inputs[i].onchange = ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" onchange="javascript:callMeOnChange()" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" value="1" maxlength="12" id="qty" name="qty" />
<div id="qtyvalue"><div>
<script>
function callMeOnChange()
{
$('#qtyvalue').value=$('#qty').val();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change button status on input field content change

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);//
        $('#captchaStatusTrue').attr('hidden',true);//
        $('#captchaStatusFalse').removeAttr('hidden');//

      document.getElementById("status").onchange = function(){ 
        var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
        var falses = "false";

       if(status == falses){//
                $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);//
                $('#captchaStatusTrue').attr('hidden',true);//
                $('#captchaStatusFalse').removeAttr('hidden');//
            }
            else{//
                   $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');//
                   $('#captchaStatusFalse').attr('hidden',true);//
                   $('#captchaStatusTrue').removeAttr('hidden');//

            }//
      };//
    </script>
```